# LG G4 ghost touch and swipe when data is turned on

Tags: mobile-data, touchscreen, lg-g4

Odd problem with my LG G4 phone, on Monday I check my whatsapp and the screen starts ghost touching itself randomly in different places?  I lock the phone to stop it and reset a couple of times, but it’s still noticeable.

At the same time that started there was a issue with my rear camera, a message kept popping up saying “unfornately the camera has stopped working”.  I eventfully got that fixed by removing the battery for a bit, no other standard troubleshooting was able to fix it?

Before I fixed the rear camera I had identified that if I switch the data connection off then the screen is fine, no ghost touches ever happen when data is off.

So I’ve been keeping my data off now until I need it, but when I turn it on the ghost touching starts near instantly.  And if it’s on, but there is no signal then it’s fine, but the moment it gets signal the ghost touches start again.

I also notice that sometimes the whole screens frame rate drops way down, almost as if I’m only viewing a remote access view of my screen??

I’m planning to do a factory reset after I get a backup setup, but looking to see if anyone has any ideas.

I haven’t installed any apps that weren’t on the play store, and I haven’t modified the OS is any way.  And it doesn’t happen when connect to WiFi

Comment: Finished the factory reset and now the ghost touches are worse than ever. Now happens whether data is on or off. It must be a hardware issue, or the screen protector??

Answer (score 1):

I may have found a solution?...  Before, I was exclusively using fast-charging.  I stopped that completely and went back to normal charge 2-3 days ago and the ghost touching has not re-occurred since!

My battery also lasts noticeably longer after a normal charge, so I think I’ll stick to this regardless.

If things change I’ll post a comment

Comment: The voltage is usually the culprit on most ghost touch cases: [How can electromagnetic interference from a USB charger cause a capacitive touchscreen to malfunction?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/72513/57290)